# Django DB records disappears after first testcase run

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project based on Django REST Framework. So I need to write some test cases for my REST API.

I've written some basic class (let's call it *BaseAPITestCase*) inherited from standard DRFs *APITransactionTestCase*.

In this class I've defined *setUp* method where I'm creating some test **user which belongs to some groups** (I'm using *UserFactory* written with FactoryBoy).

When I run my tests, the first one (first test case method from first **child** class) successfully creates a user with specified groups, but the others don't (other test case methods in the **same** class).

User groups just don't exist in DB at this time. It seems like existed records are deleted from DB at each new test case run. But how then it works for the first time?

I've read Django test documentation but can't figure out why it happens... Can anyone explain it?

The main question is **what I should do to make these tests works**?

Should I create user once and store it in object variable?

Should I add some params to preserve user groups data?

Or should I add user groups to fixtures? In that case, how can I create this fixture properly? (All related models, such as permissions and content types)

Simplified source code for illustration:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITransactionTestCase    

class BaseAPITestCase(APITransactionTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory(
            username='login',
            password='pass',
            group_names=('admin', )
        )
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.client.force_login(self.user)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.logout()    

class CampaignListTest(BaseAPITestCase):

    def test_authorized_get(self):
        # successfully gets user groups from DB

    def test_authorized_post(self):
        # couldn't find any groups
```

Comment: Do you actually need `APITransactionTestCase` rather than `APITestCase`? If not, switching to `APITestCase` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @knbk thanks. Can you explain why Transaction one works in this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) is a test case to test transactions. As such, it explicitly does not use transactions to isolate tests, as that would interfere with the behaviour of the transactions that are being tested.

To isolate tests, `TransactionTestCase` rolls back the database by truncating all tables. This is the easiest and fastest solution without using transactions, but as you noticed this will delete *all* data, including the groups that were generated in a `post_migrate` signal receiver. You can set `serialized_rollback = True` on the class, in which case it will serialize all changes to the database, and reverse these changes them after each test. However, this is *significantly* slower, and often greatly increases the time it takes to run the test suite, so this is not the default.

`TestCase` does not have this restriction, so it wraps each test case in a transaction, and each individual test in a savepoint. Roll back using transactions and savepoints is fast and allows you to keep the data that was there at the start of the transaction or savepoint. For this reason, it is preferable to use `TestCase` whenever possible.

This extends to DRF's `APITransactionTestCase` and `APITestCase`, which simply inherit from Django's test cases.

Comment: Thank you @knbk! I didn't know that there are two kinds of clearing data. As I see, developers who have originally wrote these tests didn't know this fact too, so it'll be a lot of work ahead :)